# Alternative of order by in group_concat() Impala

Tags: sql, sql-order-by, impala, group-concat

I need to order text data inside `group_concat()`. The problem is that a different sequence is returned each time.

I tried sorting in a subquery and then using `group_concat(`), but it still returns a random sequence of text data.

Comment: Without sample data and desired output, I'm not sure how anyone can help.

Comment: Also show us your current attempt.

Comment: Looks like that functionality is missing in Impala's `group_concat` and `listagg` hasn't been implemented yet. https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/IMPALA-5083 Presumably if you provided more information, someone could provide a workaround, but it likely won't be a single built-in function.

Answer (score 0):

Order by doesn't work inside group_concat in Impala since the data is spread across nodes. So, use a limit XXX in the sub_query (ensuring it's not lower than the number of rows you have) so that all of the data goes to one data node and then group_concat will work!